# Issue with enum type on doctrine's annotations

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, annotations

I use doctrine entity's annotation to generate and update my schema and i have an issue with enum field

Here is my entity

My User class :

```
<?php

namespace Schematify\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @var int
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(length=250) */
    protected $email = '';

    /** @ORM\Column(length=32,options={"default":""}) */
    protected $pasword = '';

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('visible', 'invisible')") */
    protected $status = '';


}
```

I developped a cli command named console.php in order to call all schema-tool update. When i  type `php console.php orm:schema-tool:update --force` there's always 1 query to execute :

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE status status ENUM('visible', 'invisible');
```

I use a mysql database and all my code is available here : https://github.com/talkspiritlab/schematify

Thanks

Comment: I have a similar problem with ENUM on schema-tool:update. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

To have a proper support for enum, even in schema/migrations tools, you should implement a custom type for each enums, as described in the [second solution in the official documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-2-defining-a-type).

In addition to that, don't forget to [mark them as needing comments](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2594#issuecomment-273265931):

```
Type::addType($name, $class);
$platform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping($name, $name);
$platform->markDoctrineTypeCommented($name);
```

Unless if you are using a very new version of DBAL that include [this commit](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2603/commits/fa75b7bfb51ea87b9ed4b3b33244b4c4d7eab34e), then you don't need to mark as needing comment. At the time of writing that would be master (or the hypothetical future v2.6).